# Submit button doesn't work after searching

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been looking for a solution but it was imposible. I hope it is well explained.

I have a list of users with a small form to change one of the attributes in the DB (that attribute is to know that the user has done the check-in).

[image]

There is also a searcher that shows the result with AJAX so that all the page won't be reloaded. When I load the page for the first time the browser renders HTML and the `Save` button works as expected. But when I use the searcher and the list appears (using JS) the submit button doesn't work. In Mozilla Firefox does nothing at all and in Google Chrome I get this error: `No route matches "user's profile route"`. The searcher works fine (shows the correct users). I use Rails 3.0.1 and Ruby 1.8.7

**check_in.html.erb**

Here is the searcher and the render call

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "admins", :action => "check_in"}, :id => "users_search", :method => "get", :html => {:autocomplete => "off"}) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :selected_event_id, params[:selected_event_id] %>
  <p>
     <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
     <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>    
<div id="check_in"><%= render :partial => 'check_in' %></div>
```

**_check_in.html.erb**

This is the partial that renders above

```
  <%@event_user_infos.each do |user_info|subscription = Subscription.find(:first, :conditions => ["user_id = ? and event_id = ?", user_info.user_id, params[:selected_event_id]])%>
       <%= simple_form_for(subscription) do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>  
          <%= f.hidden_field :event_id %>
          <tr>
          <td><%= link_to user_info.name, subscription %></td>
          <td><%= user_info.company %></td>
          <td><%= user_info.user.email %></td>
          <td><%= subscription.networkId %></td>
              <td><%= f.input :token, :input_html => { :size => 15, :maxlength => 15 }, :as => :integer, :label => false %></td>
              <td width='5px'>
                 <%= f.submit 'save' %>
              </td>
         </tr>
      <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

**admins_controller.rb**

I only put the relevant part of the code

```
def check_in
    event_id = params[:selected_event_id]
    if !event_id.nil?
      session[:event_id] = event_id      
      @event_user_infos = UserInfo.search(params[:search],event_id).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)
   end
end
```

**check_in.js.erb**

```
$('#check_in').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'check_in') %>');
```

**EDIT**

I added a conditional`:remote => remote` option (if there is a search `remote == true` and if is not `remote == false`) to the partial's form and the error in Google Chrome disappeared, but it still does nothing (now in both browsers). I also checked the HTML source and it seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem. I changed `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults%>` line of code for `<%= javascript_include_tag 'prototype'%>` in `application.html.erb` file and it works now in both browsers.